# How do i insert datepicker into database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to read the 'month' from table site_salmonusage.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msymt.png) is the example of data in site_salmonusage. Then i need to count whether the data is exist or not, If it exist, then i need to update all data in that 'month'. If not exist, it will insert into.

```
if ($_POST['register']){
$entry_id=$_POST["entry_id"];
$storenum = $_POST["storenum"];
$store_name=$_POST["store_name"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
$usage = $_POST["usage"];

$remove=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*)  As count FROM site_salmonusage WHERE month='$month' AND storenum='$storenum'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($remove);

if($row['count']==1){

    $add1 = "UPDATE site_salmonusage
SET  usage='$usage'
WHERE storenum='$storenum' AND month='$month'";
} 

else if($row['count']==0){
$add = "INSERT INTO site_salmonusage (storenum, month, usage)
VALUES ('$storenum','$month',$usage')";
}
else {
    $del= "DELETE  FROM site_salmonusage WHERE month='$month'"; 
    $adding="INSERT INTO site_salmonusage (storenum,month,usage)
    VALUES ('$storenum','$month','$usage')";
}
```

Here is my php. But after submit button, it not insert into database.

Comment: show the code you execute the insert query

Comment: You would be open to SQL injections if you ever executed any of those queries.

Comment: Here is my form to insert date
<input required style="width:150px;text-align:center"  name="month" class="date-picker" >

and the query in my php that i posted just now.

Comment: id you check `month` value is sent to server

Comment: no, it didnt sent to server. pls help

Comment: THANKYOU. NOW I KNOW WHY IT DIDNOT WORKING, because im using the reserved word in mysql. it is "usage". so after i change the 'usage' to something else, all the data that been entered have sent to my db. sorry for my careless